# How to add small text under an input-group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a small text under a input group. 
But it doesn't work as it works with form-group.

So in this example, I want help text to be below input, rather than being at the right of the input
This is what I mean with input group https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

This is jsfiddle link to play on it https://jsfiddle.net/c59hnx8v/

BTW this is just for demonstration.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container mt-3">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="demo">Write your email here:</label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="demo" name="email">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
            </div>
            <small>Help text</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label for="demo">Write your email here:</label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="demo" name="email">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
            </div>
            <small>Help text</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label for="demo">Write your email here:</label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="demo" name="email">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
            </div>
            <small>Help text</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label for="demo">Write your email here:</label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="demo" name="email">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
            </div>
            <small>Help text</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <label for="demo">Write your email here:</label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="demo" name="email">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
            </div>
            <small>Help text</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is similar to the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996400/using-input-groups-with-addons-together-with-help-text-in-bootstrap-4) and the problem exists because the Bootstrap 4 input-group is `display:flex`.

The simplest "fix" is to ensure the `help-text` is width:100%, and the `w-100` class can be used for this. This was no extra CSS is needed.

```
  <div class="col">
      <label for="demo">Write your email here:</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="demo" name="email">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
        </div>
        <small class="w-100">Help text</small>
      </div>
  </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/MvXabRrm2c

Comment: This removes the radius from the append, see my answer below that corrects this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your layout, you just need to make the small text's width same as its container:

```
.input-group-append + small {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying @Zim answer, I found that it removes the radius from the append, the following corrected that for me...

```
    <div class="col mb-2">
        <label for="demo">Write your email here:</label>
        <div class="input-group ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="demo" name="email">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <small class="w-100">Help text</small>
    </div>
```